# Uploading image with blueimp and function structure similar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

This is my structure:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main">

    <input type='submit' value='Go' onClick='open_form();' />


</div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: 'upload.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
function open_form() {
   $.get('test.php?rand',function(response){
        $('#main').html(response);
    });
};
```

test.php

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="server/php/" multiple>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$data = array('name' => 'Test');
echo json_encode('files' = > $data);
```

Nothing happens or triggers the upload... I assume its' perhaps something because of the function ajax requesting the function call, because the "choose file" is displayed, but nothing happens when I pick a file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKme2.png

Comment: write this in upload.php : `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
  require('UploadClass.php');
  $upload_handler = new UploadHandler(); `

Comment: Well I shouldn't need to use his PHP script right? it should technically call the upload.php file and I want to output a text (for debugging purpose right now)

Comment: I don't know what exactly is your problem. What do yo mean with "nothing happens"? Can you see (with Firebug) is there is an ajax call or not?

Comment: It is not.. updated LOG.

Comment: Look at the picture edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to attach fileupload plugin to #fileupload div when this div does not exist. The course of events in your file is:

1. find #fileupload and attach fileupload plugin to it
2. attach loading external data into main form to a button

Then, you click on a button, #fileupload is loaded, but without the plugin attached.

One of the options to fix the problem is to execute the attaching process after loading the layer - e.g. to make main.js look like this:

```
function open_form() {
    $.get('test.php?rand',function(response){
        $('#main').html(response);

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: 'upload.php',
            dataType: 'json',
                    done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: anything i can add to my question to help further?